# App_Code duplicate variable in DLLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-code

I've moved a class to the App_Code folder and I'm now receiving the following error message:

```
CS0433: The type 'myProject.App_Code.ItemType' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\
Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8cdcbe9c\
b9695514\assembly\dl3\e5cfe230\82ca7cf7_5c89ca01\myProject.DLL' and 
'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
root\8cdcbe9c\b9695514\App_Code.5kpxjdxm.dll'
```

This error is returned at runtime.

I've searched my application for any duplicate but I'm guessing this is due to something not updating as I expect?

If I move the class back outside of the App_Code folder, everything works again as expected.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sometimes it helps when you clear out all of the temporary files in c:\WINDOWS\
Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: I tried that and it started throwing the error: "Could not find a part of the path 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8cdcbe9c\b9695514\App_Web_section.aspx.d78c169f.6jztn4pf.0.cs'."

Comment: Aargh, don't you hate wrestling with this stuff? You closed and reopened Visual Studio, right? Try also clearing out C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

Comment: This is a website project, correct? What kind of file is it: a code-behind of a page, or something else?

Comment: @DOK - I tried your sugestion but still the same error. @Martin - It's a straight .cs file. Not a partial class (code behind) or anything. Just a straight class.

Comment: If we don't come up with the answer, you can actually find some stuff by googling "CS0433". One suggests that perhaps you need to change the namespace of the class file now that it's in APP_Code. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @DOK. I've changed the namespace so that it's the same as a class I add directly to App_Code. It's an odd one but my last resort is to move the classes back out of the App_Code folder. I still wanna know what I'm doing wrong though.

Comment: myProject.dll looks like you are using WebApplication while the App_Code folder looks like you are using WebSite. Could you please mention what type of project is this?

Comment: I've inherited this project from someone else and I'm not sure how to tell which type it is? Under the 'Build' menu option I have only 'Build' and 'Publish' if that's any help?

Comment: I've also just tried the same code on another persons machine and the same error is thrown. Seems kinda odd.

Comment: @Jamie - If the menu is not saying "Build Website" it is most likely a WebApplication. To the best of my knowledge a Web Application cannot have "App_Code" Asp.NET folder. 

Check do you have a AssemblyInfo.cs in your project. If it exisits, then it confirms its a web application.

Comment: @Jamie - I tried creating a App_Code folder and moved a class file in it. The application is able to run fine.

Comment: @Ramesh. I've got lots of classes inside my App_Code folder. It's only this particular one that's giving me a problem. If i move this one outside of the App_code folder then the rest works fine. :(

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

- clearing the referenced `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder and restarting Visual Studio ?

Comment: close VS first and tehen remove everything from the temp directory and then reload the project.

Comment: Try adding `batch='false'` to the compilation element of the web.config.

Comment: Thanks ChristopheD. The same error still shows after doing that though.

Comment: @Jamie Dixon: Why was this the accepted answer? Was the problem resolved? I have the same issue

Comment: @Sehe, This was a loooong time ago. As I recall I ended up moving the file in question out of the App_Code folder. As for why this answer was accepted, Good question!

Comment: @Jamie Dixon: thanks anyway for the clarification; I'll let you know whether a cleanup of App_code fixed it on our server :) (I don't have access, so I'll have to wait)

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy the file into app_code instead of moving it? Or have you created a backup copy of the file/page/control?

These could also be reasons for the error message.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I've tried it both ways and both return the same error.